# Delay an Intent after multiple onClicks?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I am creating an app which asks the user a series of question consecutively one after the other. However. The final question I ask is "Is the information correct?"

I need this prompt to appear at least 3000ms after the other series of consecutive questions in order for the user to look at the recorded information first and see if it is all correct. However at the moment, regardless of using a handler the final prompt appears immediately after the second last question. Is there a way of getting a delay of at least 3000ms before the final prompt appears?

Below is part of my current code which I am referring to. Please note I have tried the handler in both onClick as well as in the onActivityResult section.

If someone can kindly provide the correct bit of code that will be greatly appreciated.

```
public void onClick(View v){

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent i1 = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        i1.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        i1.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Is the information correct? (Yes/No)");
        startActivityForResult(i1, check);
    }
}, 3000);


Intent i2 = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
i2.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
i2.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "What is the current time?");
startActivityForResult(i2, checklv1);

Intent i3 = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
i3.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
i3.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Is the status Confirmed or Unconfirmed?");
startActivityForResult(i3, checklv2);

Intent i4 = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
i4.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
i4.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "What is the temp?");
startActivityForResult(i4, checklv3);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == check && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
    lv4.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));}
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == checklv1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
    lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));}
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == checklv2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
    lv2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));}
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == checklv3 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
    lv3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));}
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

(UPDATED) If I user a Timer, I have the following code but where have I gone wrong and where do I place the `super.onActivityResult...`?

```
        if (requestCode == check && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        lv4.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
            new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    // Do nothing for your logic.
                }
                public void onFinish() {
                    // Your logic here.

                }
            }.start();}}
```

Comment: I think this is not right way to do what u want. why not using `onActivityResult ` for starting next question when previous is done?

Comment: Hmm, I tried it in `onActivityResult` but still couldn't get the delay to work @ρяσѕρєя K.  Are you able to please help me with adjusting the above code provided please

Comment: Show your code using onActivityResult

Comment: Okay @ρяσѕρєя K, I have uploaded the code above, please check and let me know where I have gone wrong. thanks

Comment: you can use service ,countdown timer and local broadcast receiver to acheive your goal .

Answer (score 2):

Instead of handler you can use Countdowntimer.

```
new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     // Do nothing for your logic.
  }
  public void onFinish() {
    // Your logic here.
  }
}.start();
```

Comment: Hmm sounds very interesting, does this occur within `onActivityResult` and how would I assign it to `lv4`?

Comment: you can assign lv4 in onFinish() which execute after 3 second. you can change the duration according to your requirement

Comment: great, so part of my code has `if (requestCode == check...` and then ends with `super.onActivityResult...` does this all also go in the `onFinish` section?

Comment: No. Inside if (requestCode == check.. you write this new CountDowntimer... inside onFinish() you write your logic.

Comment: okay, I have updated the above code to show what I have understood from you so far. can you see if I am on the right track.  Where do I need to put the `super.onActivityResult....` part?

Comment: you need to call lv4 inside onFinish() so that lv4 will call after 3 second.

Comment: I'm still a bit lost with what you mean. Are you able to kindly upload the way the code should be arranged..please

Comment: If you can please provide some more calrification @Andy Developer that will be appreciated.  I'm having some issues with the placements of your code with mine as Updated above

Answer (score 0):

Try using setClickable method https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable(boolean)

```
public void onClick(final View v){
    v.setClickable(false);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i1 = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            i1.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            i1.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Is the information correct? (Yes/No)");
            v.setClickable(true);
            startActivityForResult(i1, check);
        }
    }, 3000);
```